# Переименование столбцов при LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Добрый день ! Допустим есть конструкция

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field = table2.field
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.field = table3.field
```

можно ли модицифировать запрос чтобы переименовать table2.id ?

Comment: Если переименовать поле в  выходном наборе - то, как уже отвечено, алиас в помощь. Если же надо переименовать поле в таблице - то одним запросом это невозможно.

Answer (score 3):

Естественно, любой столбец можно переименовать. Но для этого в секции запроса `SELECT` надо вместо использования `*` перечислить нужные столбцы (если нужны все столбцы, то перечисляем все). И тогда для каждого столбца можно указать псевдоним (alias). Например: `SELECT table2.id AS your_alias FROM ...`. Псевдонимы можно задавать как с помощью `AS`, так и без него.